# Is it possible to know how many urls are totally shared on Facebook by querying the link_stat table?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible to know how many urls are totally shared on Facebook by querying the link_stat table?

I haven't found a way to do so because of the restrictions of FQL.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because of several things:

- `list_stats` table have `url` as indexable field, so you need to know exact URLs to get results
- there is no aggregation function in FQL which can count rows (like `COUNT()` in SQL)